# How not to allow generating selection using comma and tab jquery autosuggest?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hey guys, I'm using JQuery's autosuggest and it's working great, just one question. If a user types something and it's not there he could simply click comma or tab and he adds the value. My question is, how can I disable that and allow him only to select the results and nothing else?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    var data = {items: [
    <?php 

    $mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','samaniac','ghobisdabomb');
    mysql_select_db('jmtdy');
    $result=mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $dbarray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $result2=mysql_query("select * from friendship where userid='".$dbarray['id']."'");
    while($dbarray2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $result3=mysql_query("select * from users where id='".$dbarray2['friendid']."'");
        $dbarray3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);


        echo '{value: "'.$dbarray3['id'].'", name: "'.$dbarray3['username'].'"},';
        }
        ?>
]};
$("#suggestedfriend").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name", asHtmlID: "clippedon", startText: "Enter Username",retrieveLimit:5});
});







</script>
```

And yes I know I'm using php in my jquery script, but it's working just the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an combo plugin and not autosuggest. The autosuggest per definition only suggests and not forces, the work to customise jquery autosuggest has largest than you use a combo plugin

try this
http://code.google.com/p/sexy-combo/

Comment: Is there no hack or tweak that I can use to make it work? I really like the way autosuggest looks and feels.

Comment: Very hard to answer without see your code, but sexy-combo provides the same user experience of jquery autosuggest.

Comment: Why would you need the code? I will post it anyway in my question.